# What would cause TreeView_InsertItem to fail?

Tags: c++, windows, treeview, wxwidgets

On a few computers computers (meaning most are fine), when adding an item to a tree control, for some reason `TreeView_InsertItem` returns `NULL` ([Indicating something went wrong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx%20%22here)).
Unfortunately the MSDN site doesn't specify that an error code is set (and indeed, calling [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) simply tells me: `0 = The operation completed successfully`.
Neither does it specify what could cause a failure or how to deal with one.

So I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this before, or has any suggestions as to how to debug the problem.

The machines are all running Windows 7.

A disclaimer: I'm actually going through `wxWidgets`, but we've dug into the code and the problem  appears to lie at the windows `api` level, and not with `wx` itself.

**Update:**
Basically, the idea is, you inherit from this class, and then implement populate, which simply calls `AddItem()`. There is also a version of `AddItem()` for specifying the root item, but since I fail on the first call to `Append()`, it's presence doesn't help.
The tree is created in `wxFormBuilder` with the following flags: `wxTR_DEFAULT_STYLE, wxTR_HAS_BUTTONS, wxTR_HIDE_ROOT, wxTR_LINES_AT_ROOT, wxTR_SINGLE`

This also works perfectly fine from my own PC

```
ItemSelector::ItemSelector( wxWindow* parent )
:    m_tree( NULL ),
    m_initialised( false )
{
    wxXmlResource::Get()->LoadFrame( this, parent, wxT( "ItemSelector" ) );

    m_tree = XRCCTRL( *this, "itemTree", wxTreeCtrl );

    m_rootItem = m_tree->AddRoot( wxT( "ROOT" ) );

    Bind( wxEVT_SHOW, &ItemSelector::OnShow, this );

    MakeModal( true );
}

void ItemSelector::OnShow( wxShowEvent& event )
{
    if( event.IsShown() )
    {
        if( !m_initialised )
        {
            Populate();
            m_initialised = true;
        }

        m_tree->SetFocus();
        Layout();
    }
}

void ItemSelector::AddItem( const wxString& name, void* someData )
{
    //Also tried m_tree->AppendItem( m_rootItem, wxT( "Test" ) ) - same problem
    wxTreeItemId newItem = m_tree->AppendItem( m_rootItem, name, -1, -1, new TreeDataClass( someData ) );
}
```

Comment: All TreeView_InsertItem does is send a message to a control (through, actually) There are many things that can go wrong with this, mostly state-based on the window handle representing the control; Code = does-wonders. Show please.

Comment: I've edited the original post with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was due to the fact that I was calling `Populate()` from an `wxEVT_SHOW` event.

I've discovered that this must be a known problem, because `wxDialog` has a `[wxEVT_INIT_DIALOG][1]` event, precisely for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything really wrong in your code but it's quite strange. First of all, why do you call deprecated `MakeModal()` instead of making your class a `wxDialog` and using its `ShowModal()`? Second, why wait until `wxEVT_SHOW` with populating the control instead of doing it immediately?

I'd advise to simplify your code as indicated and I think the problem will disappear. If you're curious, you could then bisect your changes to find the one that was really responsible for it.

Comment: Populate() is a pure virtual function and so cannot be called from a constructor. I figured wxEVT_SHOW was probably the simplest solution to that problem

Thanks for the info on MakeModal(), I'll make sure to fix that

Comment: Thanks VZ, it looks like wxEVT_SHOW was the problem after all